# get tableau users on all pages in python

Tags: python, pagination, python-import, tableau-api

I am pulling user details from tableau server in python but I am getting details of users on first page only. This is because default page number is set to 1 and even if I change it to 2 I get users that are on 2nd page.How do I get users on all the pages ?
please help, this is my code

```
> import tableauserverclient as TSC
> tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('userid', 'passoword', 'site') server = TSC.Server('http link')
> with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
> requestoptions = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000, pagenumber=1)
> all_users, pagination_item = server.users.get(req_options=requestoptions)
> print("\nThere are {} user on site:".format(pagination_item.total_available))   
> print([user.name for user in all_users])
> tdata = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([user.name for user in all_users])   
> print(tdata)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the users by

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
server = TSC.Server('https://SERVERURL')

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    all_users, pagination_item = server.users.get()
    print("\nThere are {} user on site: ".format(pagination_item.total_available))
    print([user.name for user in all_users])
```

[See](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#users) for more operations

Comment: please see my code. Its exactly the same. If the users are over 1000 then it goes to the next page. That's why I need users that are on the other page too.

Comment: You can first fetch the count of users and decide the number of pages dividing total count by the records of each page

Comment: I already have the count of pages. I want to know how to print all users at once

Comment: `print([user for user in all_users])`